Incorrect Date Formatting in .NET 6 with DateOnly Type
I'm facing an issue with the DateOnly type in a .NET 6 API where the date format is not mapped correctly when passed via a query parameter. The expected date format is dd.MM.yyyy, which is standard for Norway, but it's being interpreted as MM.dd.yyyy instead.
Here's the relevant part of my controller:
[HttpGet("data")]
public Task<IActionResult> GetData([FromQuery] DateOnly date)
{
    return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(Ok($"Day {date.Day} Month {date.Month} Year {date.Year}"));
}

And here's an example request:
http://localhost:7053/data?date=01.04.2024

However the output is:
Day 04 Month 01 Year 2024

This indicates that the date is being interpreted as Jauary 4th, 2024, rather than April 1st, 2024. The application's culture is set to Norway, where the standard date format is dd.MM.yyyy. I'm looking for a solution that specifically works with the DateOnly type, without resorting to using DateTime. I am aware that DateTime could be used as a workaround, but I need a solution that adheres to using DateOnly.
Has anyone encountered this issue or know of a way to ensure the correct date format is used with DateOnly in .NET 6?

Out of curiosity, why not pass in your date as yyyy-MM-dd, the ISO standard, rather than expecting a particular country's format? (which may or may not still require your own binder code)

DateOnly has no format, it's a binary value. Why use a custom format instead of the ISO format expected and understood by all web services ? Using ISO8601 is explicitly specified as the standard date format for JSON payloads

"The expected date format is dd.MM.yyyy" - That expectation seems to be wrong. " I am aware that DateTime could be used as a workaround" - could it, though? I would expect the same issues with DateTime as witth DateOnly since this is quite likely a culture-settings problem.

That is true. We can use ISO standard date format. However I am in a new project and DateOnly is used in many places and almost all calls. So I had to find a solution without touching the calls. So, yes. Maybe implementing ISO standard date format is the best option. Then we have to redo some of the work and test it @gunr2171

@Fildor no. I have changed the service culture to Norwegian but didn't help unfortunately.
